# Cogre (CEDET) can't find Graphviz

Tags: cedet

I recently installed Graphviz and Cogre to make UML diagrams in Emacs. Though when I run cogre-uml-quick-class with the Class name, it says "Layout engine failed. You need to install Graphviz".

The problem is I have installed Graphviz and it is working properly, I have tried making sample graphs and compiling them in graphviz dot mode and I have graphviz-dot-mode.el in my load path.

I added this to my .emacs file

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/cedet/srecode")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/cedet/cogre")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/graphviz-dot-mode-20150525.1000")

(load-file "~/.emacs.d/elpa/graphviz-dot-mode-20150525.1000/graphviz-dot-mode.el")
```

I'm using Emacs 24.4 on Windows 8.1

Cogre - http://cedet.sourceforge.net/cogre.shtml

Graphviz - http://www.graphviz.org/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might want to provide some links to the programs you mention, to save others the trouble of googling for them.

Comment: Iirc Graphiz is in the contrib directory, you might need to require it separately.

Comment: Where is the contrib directory? I didn't find anything under contrib of cedet and there's no other contrib directory under Graphviz